# Unable to :include model with two relations

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to model a table with host records (id, hostname, netid) and a table with routing connections which represents a connection between two routes (id, src_id,src_ip,dst_id,dst_ip).

When I attempt to retrieve all the routing records for a host and :include the host table (so that I can get the hostnames), it only retrieves the routing records. What am I doing wrong?

```
class Host < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :routes
end

class Route < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :srchost, :class_name => 'Host', :foreign_key => 'src_id'
  belongs_to :dsthost, :class_name => 'Host', :foreign_key => 'dst_id'
end

x = Route.where(:src_id => host).includes(:srchost, :dsthost)
puts x.inspect
```

Comment: You'll probably want to try this: `Route.includes(:host).where(:src_id => host)`

Comment: Thanks but there is no association named host. I get the error 'Association named 'host' was not found'

Comment: Does it work when you just replace `:host` with `:srchost, :dsthost`?

Answer (score 1):

use custom sql because includes don't return association model. Route.find_by_sql('select hosts.* ...') or you can use joins insted of includes and select('hosts.*'). Example:

```
User.joins(:posts).select('posts.title')
```